# Function bisection method in C - the function doesn't change signs in either of intervals

Tags: c, function

Hello everyone and thanks for reading.

I have come across a problem which requires me to implement the bisection method in C. I understand it is fairly easy to accomplish, but the task I was given has a little "twist" added to it.

The bisection method is used for finding roots of functions. It works by halving the given interval into two sub-intervals. We firstly check if the function is zero at any of the three points(**A** - beginning, **C** - midpoint, **B** - end), and if not, we then determine at which sub-interval **the function changes signs**. For example, if f(A) * f(C) <0 the function changes signs in the first sub-interval. If the function changes signs in both sub-intervals, we continue the search in the first one.

However, here's the catch: The exercise says that if the function doesn't change signs in either of the sub-intervals, we proceed to search for the root **in both of the sub-intervals**. I am having problems implementing the last part.

Here is what I tried:

```
double bisect(double A, double B)
{
    double epsilon=0.0001
    double C;
    while(fabs(B-A)>0.001) {
        C=(A+B)/2;



         if(fabs(f(A))<epsilon) {   //root is A
            return A;

        }

        else if(fabs(f(B))<epsilon) { //root is B
            return B;
        }

        else if(fabs(f(C))<epsilon) { // root is C
            return C;
        }

        if(f(A)*f(C)<0 && f(C)*f(B)<0) { // function changes sign in both subintervals
                                         //if that is the case, we take the first one
            B=C;
        }

        else if(f(C)*f(B)<0) { // the function changes signs only in second interval
            A=C;
        }
        else {
                    // ?? here comes the part I am having problems implementing.
          A=H;
           }


    }



    return 0;
}
```

No matter what I tried I couldn't implement it the way it is asked. How do I continue the search in both sub-intervals? Is it even possible after halving the first interval into two?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your function `bisect(A, B)` searches for roots in the interval from `A` to `B`, and you have calculated a midpoint `C`, what can you do to search for a root from `A` to `C` and to search for a root from `C` to `B`? Can you think of a function call you can make that will search for a root in the interval from `A` to `C`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see. I am having problems with recursion in general. Thank you.